# .htaccess; redirect all https:// to http:// expect of two domains

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have this code to redirect all `https://` to `http://`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But how can I exclude two domains www.example.com and www.test.com from this rule?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.)?(?:test|example)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include two Rewrite Conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.test\.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NC]
```

This will excluded both of those domains as well as any directories within the domain and keep them as HTTPs. So your code should now look like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.test\.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Make sure you clear your cache **before** testing this.